# How do I find all expression "variable = variable;" in the Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio-2008

I want to find all expression `variable = variable;` in my source files. I use Visual Studio 2008.

The `variable` is any variable, for example `x`, `i`, `k123`, `incr15`.

Samples:

```
x = x;           // Should find
x = y;           // No match
ss12 = ss12;     // Should find
ss12 = ss12 + 1; // No match
```

Comment: Did you mean variable1 = variable2 where variableN is any identifier?

Comment: No, of course! `x=x;`, `i=i;`, `some12=some12;` and similar expressions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the Find-dialog with regex ...

```
{:a+} = \1
```

will do the trick.
:a is any alphanumeric character
\1 is a backreference to everything included in {}

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs(VS.80).aspx) for more infos.

**EDIT** - in reply to the comment:

```
^:b*{:a+}:b*=:b*\1;
```

^ is the beginning of a line
:b is tab/space

**EDIT2:** As Kobi wrote, you should maybe use :i instead of :a

Comment: See my updated answer - btw. you can use $ to identify the end of a line, too ...

Comment: Both of them give false positives unless you also check the Match Case and Match Whole Word boxes (not needed for second option)

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
^:Zs+{:i}:Zs*=:Zs*\1;
```

Data can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs%28VS.80%29.aspx

It sould also be said that such a statement gives a compilation warning:

> Assignment made to same variable; did you mean to assign something else?

Comment: +1 - the :i is even better than my :a, but my :b is better than your :Zs ^^

Answer (score 0):

use regular expression search.

e.g.: \w* = \w*

Comment: +1 Was reasonable at the time the original question was posted.

Answer (score 0):

Use 'Find in Files' functionality with 'regular expressions' selected.

Something like this should do it:

\w+\s*=\s*\w+;

Answer (score 0):

Use the 'Find In Files' search.

Select/highlight your expression, then press
`CTRL + SHIFT + F` and then click on 'Find In Files' button on the 'Find and Replace' dialog that opens

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried the "Find all References" feature on the context menu?